# Problem Placing Polygon Pour on Board Altium 17.1

Tags: altium, copper-pour

I'm laying out a two-layer PCB. I've routed all the signals, including power and ground. I like to add a ground plane on both layers by placing polygon pours.

I'm having trouble getting Altium to pour the polygon, and I'm not sure why. I've placed a circular keep-out layer, convert it to polygon and tried pouring, but no polygon had formed.

I thought it was a clearance issue, since the traces on my board are pretty crowded, but after changing the clearance value, I still can't place the pour. I've even changed the air gap value for the polygon pour. I have no idea why at this point.

Attached is the picture of the board, and the link to the .PcbDoc file too.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I kept getting the error Modified Polygon: Polygon Not Repour After Edit

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aem0g2JZH2BVgYKAJDZJzsjJOqdnDD1W

[image]

Comment: thank you!its help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this: Draw a circle on the top layer & select it.

Tools->Convert->Create Polygon from Selected Primitives

Double click on polygon and select Fill Mode -> Solid Copper

Tools->Polygon Pours-> Repour All

---

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to do it? I followed your steps exactly, and still couldn't generate the pour.  My board radius is 19mm, so if drawing a circle on the top layer (instead of keep-out), should it also be 19mm? I did this and I had new errors at the perimeter of the board. Also, should I select the option Remove Dead Copper under the Properties for Polygon Pour?

Comment: Yes, it worked on 16.1. It appears to create the actual copper pour the design rule spacing inside the copper circle that was initially placed (so half the line width plus the spacing in the design rules less radius). If you delete that original top layer circle it (and repour) it will fill out to the full radius you originally drew. If you choose remove dead copper you'll have to make sure the polygon is connected to a net.

Comment: P.S. It worked for me on a board of my own. It does not seem to work on yours and I'm actually not sure why.

Comment: So you are saying that you tried it out on my board and it didn't?

Comment: Yes and I just found the problem. You have your board outline clearance set to 30mm! Changed that to 0.1mm and it works just fine.

In general you want to make all those errors go away as you work, not allow them to accumulate, especially when they go over the default 500 limit where it stops counting.

Comment: Ah thanks so much!! It may not be related, but how do you know which value of clearance is a safe value to set? I'm new to Altium

Comment: I think this really depends on the PCB vendor you are using (& PCBA vendor).

Comment: How do you determine the number of errors? Also, two more questions, forgive me if this is the wrong place.

Comment: Tools->Design Rule Check. For more questions open a new question is better.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask a new question regarding the error, but should I place a pour on both layers for ground, or one for a power line?